# is it possible to inherit class into @managedbean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

i am using jsf 2.1.26 , and primefaces 3.5
here is the code..

**HescoBusinessBean**

```
 public abstract class HescoBusinessBean {

    private String mod = "";
    // setter and getter
    }
```

**BudgetReservedBean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "budgetReservedBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BudgetReservedBean extends HescoBusinessBean implements Serializable {

// other beans properties with setter and getter
}
```

**BudgetReservedAction**

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BudgetReservedAction implements Serializable {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{budgetReservedBean}")
    private BudgetReservedBean budgetReservedBean;

// setter and getter

}
```

**abc.xhtml**

```
<h:outputText value="#{budgetReservedAction.budgetReservedBean.mod}" />
<!--where 'mod' property in HescoBusinessBean-->
```

*// getting error on server log*

```
org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "mod" "mod "" at line 1, column 43.
Was expecting:
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
```

can anyone help me out ? thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect that mod is an EL reserved keyword. Can you rename that property? Bean inheritance should work the way you have done it.

Comment: i haved changed `mod` to `modBean` and its working..

Comment: Great, let me add an answer!

Comment: i had use `mod` keyword on many .java classes but for the first time i have used it on .xhtml, is there any best way to change `mod` property to `modBean` in all .java classes rather than changing it one by one on eclipse kepler?

Comment: This is another question, I don't know the answer, but I suspect it depends in the used IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mod` is an EL reserved word. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnail.html) the list of all reserverd words.

Your implementation of bean inheritance is correct.